# Prove the Following. Let $V$ be a vector space, $\vec{u}$ a vector in $V$, and $k$ a scalar, then $k O=O$, where $O$ is the zero matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure what the $\vec{u}$ has to do with the problem since it seems like I am only proving for the scalar. Do I have to use the $\vec{u}$ to find out something about the zero matrix through axioms?

Comment: Is that the original question? The statement of $u$ seems weird to me.

Comment: u is a vector inside of the vector space. Sorry that was very unclear in the question

Comment: I don't see how $u$ is useful here then.

Comment: That is what I am also struggling with on this problem. This seems like there is very little information provided and that this proof is a basic statement. Any ideas of how to approach this?

Comment: What is meant by "matrix" here? Linear maps in $V\to V$?

Comment: is $V$ just a general vector space? From the context it seems as though it is a vector space of matrices in which case $u$ might be useful. Otherwise you have to specify what this zero matrix is. Multiplication by scalar is only defined for members of the vector space.